# Why do I need to write static get parameters()

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I been trying to migrate my Ionic 1 application to Ionic 2 and have been encountering alot of new terms and problems.

I do not really understand the need for get parameters() and when and what variables to return in that function.

For example(To Navigate):

```
 static get parameters() {
    return [[NavController]];
 }
```

Previously in an older ionic build(I'm not sure which version I was developing upon), I can navigate to pages without this function. In the latest ionic 2 build(2.0.0-beta.25) , without this get parameters() function, it just wont navigate to the next targeted page , but there are no errors.

I'm aware of a existing post:
[Angular/Ionic 2 - what is a provider and what does `static get parameters()` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35922092/angular-ionic-2-what-is-a-provider-and-what-does-static-get-parameters-do)

Therefore, in what occasion I should return and what variables do I return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ES6 dependency injection gets the list of types it needs to resolve and pass instances for to the constructor of the class.

It has to be static, otherwise they **could not** be read **before** an instance is created.

In TypeScript it can aquire these types from the constructor parameters if they are applied (or `@Inject()` annotations).

Return the types for the constructor parameters of your class in the order they are listed in the constructor parameter list.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34546344/217408 for an example.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, Angular2 tries to find out what to inject into the constructor of the class using the `parameters` method of the `ReflectionCapabilities` class:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/core/reflection/reflection_capabilities.ts#L126

This method tries several things:

- within the `parameters` of the type (i.e. a class property, i.e. static property)

  ```
  @Component({
    (...)
  })
  export class SomeComponent {
    constructor(http) {
    }

    static get parameter() {
      return [[Http]];
    }
  }
  ```
- within the `parameters` metadata for the class if any. It's populated by `@Inject` decorator. Not that parameter decorators aren't supported in ES6

  ```
  @Component({
    (...)
  })
  export class SomeComponent {
    constructor(@Inject(Http) http) { // == http:Http
    }
  }
  ```
- within the `design:paramtypes` metadata that is internally created using the parameter types of the constructor. With ES6, this metadata isn't available since types for method parameters can't be used.

  ```
  @Component({
    (...)
  })
  export class SomeComponent {
    constructor(http:Http) {
    }
  }
  ```

Based on these types, Angular2 looks for corresponding providers to get instances to inject.